# React Trello - Card properties

Tags: reactjs, trello

I'm using React Trello with a custom card component:

```
             <Board
                data={{ lanes }}
                editable={false}
                components={{ NewCardForm: CardForm, **Card: TrelloCard** }}
                style={{ background: 'transparent' }}
            />
```

In my Trello card component, I'm getting all card props, but I want to pass extra props, and I'm wondering how I can do it?

Comment: Needs more details. Show us the code of the `TrelloCard` component that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

Create your custom card component:

```
function Card(props) {
 const {yourProps} = props;
 return (<div>{yourProps}</div>)
}
```

Create the components object (or use it directly in the Board Component):

```
const components = {
  Card: (props) => Card({ ...props, yourProps: 'hello world' }),
};
```

Then in your component:

```
<Board
  data={data}
  components={components}
/>
```